# Push notification badge not disappearing

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I implemented push notification. It works well apart from the badge that always shows "1".

My code looks like this:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
"debug": true
});
push.register(function(token) {
console.log("Device token:",token.token);
//Here I make an http post to my server to store device token
push.saveToken(token); // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
});
```

Whats wrong? I tried to google "ionic badge remove" but no good hits. What I understood badge should disappear as soon as you click on the app. But it doesn't (Im testing on a real iphone 6).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can clear that kind of notification, the way I know to solve this problem is use [Local Notification Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) to handle your push notifications.